# Passing value from functional component in React

Tags: reactjs, functional-programming, components

I'm new to ReactJS and JavaScript and right now I'm developing a small student project using those technologies.

I have a problem with a piece of my code:

```
import './List.css';
import Bin from './bin.png'
function List({items, listName, accessCode, onBinClick, onNameClick}){
    return(
        <div className="listDiv">
            <div className="nameDiv">
                <input type="text" placeholder={listName} maxLength="15" spellCheck="false"></input>
            </div>
            <div className="codeDiv">
                {accessCode}
            </div>
            <br/>
            {items.map(item => (
                <div className="itemDiv" id={item.id} key={item.id}>
                    <span onClick = {onNameClick}>{item.name}</span>
                    <img src={Bin} width="30" alt="Delete item" onClick={onBinClick}></img>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}

export default List;
```

I would like to pass to a parent an id of div in which the bin icon (img) was clicked and then do sth with this value in parent component.

I've tried replacing

```
onClick={onBinClick}
```

with

```
onClick={onBinClick(item.id)}
```

but it doesn't work the way I would like it to - surely because of my lack of knowledge.

I will be glad if you could come up with a hint how to solve that issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share how `onNameClick` is implemented?

Comment: Thanks for response. Either `onNameClick` or `onBinClick` are only printing message to a console. In future I'd like them to print the clicked item id (passed by List component to the parent component)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pass a function to onClick handlers. Using ES6 syntax, you can write what you are attempting to do like this `onClick={() => onBinClick(item.id)}`. If you just call the function in onClick, it passes the return value of that function, not the function itself.

Comment: Awesome, thats exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for fast answer and short clean explanation. Cheers!

Comment: Awesome, do you mind accepting the answer by clicking the checkmark to the left?

Comment: I wanted to mark it immediately but had to wait a few minutes - should be marked now.